# Postgres Non-overlapping time period using Gist with constraints

Tags: postgresql

I have a twist on the usual "non-overlapping" time periods using Gist

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
id serial,
company_id int NOT NULL,
primarylisting boolean NOT NULL,
validrange daterange NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT foo_primarykey PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE);
```

I have the table above which has (foreign key) company_ids and I am creating securityids.

Each company can have many securities at any time, but only one security can be the primary security. I suspect its something like the following but can't find an example to follow:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT unique_primarylisting_daterange 
EXCLUDE USING gist (company_id WITH =,validrange WITH &&) where primarylisting=1;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT unique_primarylisting_daterange 
EXCLUDE USING gist (company_id WITH =,validrange WITH &&, primarylisting WITH =1);
```

note that it can't be primarylisting WITH = because while I can't have multiple primary securities at any one point, I can have multiple non-primary securities.

thanks

Comment: `EXCLUDE USING gist (company_id WITH =, validrange WITH &&) WHERE (primarylisting)` [should work](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE). (that will be a partial exclusion constraint.) -- You'll want to use the [`btree_gist` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) too.

Comment: Winner! Thanks - not sure how to mark this as the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got the [right syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) first time.

But `WHERE` predicate for partial constraints (and indexes) needs to be in parenthesis. Also, you shouldn't compare a `BOOLEAN` column to `1` (you could use `bool_col = TRUE`, `bool_col IS TRUE` or just `bool_col`):

```
ALTER TABLE foo
  ADD CONSTRAINT unique_primarylisting_daterange 
  EXCLUDE USING gist (company_id WITH =, validrange WITH &&) WHERE (primarylisting);
```